# Difference between strillare, gridare, sgridare, urlare, rampognare

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, difference, synonym

Have some problem to understand difference  between subject.
It all means scream, but I suppose with some difference.
I'll write what I think, correct me, if I'm wrong.

Strillare - scream, but very high voice, like ultrasound )

Urlare - see no difference with strillare, but more like "howl"?

Gridare - i see in dictionaries mean "scream", but I think main meaning is(`well I don't know english word either, but can assume`) "berating someone".

Sgridare - gridare with higher voice?

Rampognare - have no idea what difference with "gridare"

P.S. I can't use monolingual dictionaries. Not enough knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better meaning for *strillare* is *to screech*; *urlare* is *to scream*, and is mostly synonymous with *gridare*.

The meaning of *sgridare* is *to berate*, *to scold*, usually with a high voice, but not necessarily.

Finally, *rampognare* is a (not common nowadays) word for *to reproach*; more common would be *rimproverare* (or also *sgridare*).

Answer (score 2):

*Strillare*, *gridare*, *urlare* are all synonyms, as well as *schiamazzare*, *strepitare* and they all relate to loudness.

*Gridare* has also to do with the intention to "let people know" about something (*Gridare ai quattro venti*), in fact "Grida" also indicates medieval official communications to population.

*Sgridare* and *rampognare* (along with *strillare*, *rimbrottare*, *redarguire* and more...) mean to reproach or berate

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE and thanks for your contribution. I would say there are some different nuances in meaning and usage among some of the synonyms you have mentioned, isn't it?

Comment: I've found that "schiamazzare and strepitare" are used when there is bunch of people, crowd(folla). And first one also used for chicken or duck "voice", is that correct? Rimbrottare are low voice, when i say something for myself? Redarguire are "reproach" but not when standing in front of person, but when nobody hears it?

Comment: @DuhVir: You are mixing up _rimbrottare_ (to scold) and _borbottare_ (to mumble or to grumble).

Comment: @Charo Thank you. Yes, sure there are some different nuances, in some cases it also depends on the area the speaker is from, even being from a few miles away could make a difference :)

Comment: @DuhVir and DaG, *rimbrottare* certainly means *to reproach*, but I'd use some other form if the reproaching is not loud.
*Redarguire* is generic reproaching, it depends on the context, it's not related to loudness; it may simply mean *explaining* or *informing* why something is wrong / how to do it right.
*Schiamazzare* is usually meant when a bunch of people are too loud, I'd add in an open space or heard from outside. But it can be referred to a single person (*schiamazzi notturni* is a specific crime)
*Strepitare* is not so common, it has to do with the noise / voice being very acute